# how to get the key information from a KeyError

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

Is there a way to get the key that raised a `KeyError`?

or in general, where can I find (if available) properties of an `Exception`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exceptions have a [`.args` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException.args) which is a tuple; for a `KeyError` exception that tuple contains the key that triggered the exception:

```
>>> try:
...     {}['foo']
... except KeyError as ex:
...     print(ex.args[0])
... 
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
d = dict(a=1)
try:
    d['b']
except KeyError as e:
    print e
```

Output:

```
'b'
```